# Shell script call command line application

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have a Java program which I'd like to call inside a linux shell script. The Java program takes a user input from the command line.

I read somewhere that I can use echo to mimic user input as follows:

```
 java myProgram
 echo 1000
 echo
```

However this doesn't work for me, the program is still waiting for the user input. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I can't imagine this is a difficult task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `echo`, but in a pipeline.

```
echo 1000 | java myProgram
```

If you want to send a file, you can use `cat`:

```
cat file.txt | java myProgram
```

Comment: +1. In some shells, such as Bash, the first version can also be written as `java myProgram <<<1000`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis No. stdin is different from passing arguments.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: No; pipes pass the standard output of one simple command to the standard input of the next. To pass the output of a command as an argument, you would write something like `java myProgram "$(the_command)"` or `the_command | xargs java myProgram`.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just pass in the value as an argument

```
java myProgram 1000
```

Comment: Program seems to take standard input.

Comment: Ofc a little refactoring necessary but should simplify

Answer (score 0):

I think you should find the process id of your java process and then write to its `/proc` directory.

Say the id of the Java process is `4321`, then output to

```
/proc/4321/fd/0
```